# Clear selection of Wicket ListMultipleChoice

Tags: wicket-6

How can I programmatically clear the selection of a ListMultipleChoice component in wicket 6.19?

I have several ListMultipleChoice components which I use to filter a table on. Everything works ok, except in the case when I reset the filters.
The selections remain highlighted in the choices. How can I reset them to the initial unselected state?

Clearing the resulting list of selections doesn't seem to be sufficient.

Here are some more details, what I tried:

```
    sapSystemNames = new ListMultipleChoice<String>("selectedSystemNames", new IModel<List<String>>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -1521113613671111638L;

        @Override
        public void detach() {
            // nothing to do here
        }

        @Override
        public List<String> getObject() {
            return selectedSystemNames;
        }

        @Override
        public void setObject(List<String> object) {
            selectedSystemNames = object;
        }

    }, new LoadableDetachableModel<List<String>>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -2685944576502559429L;

        @Override
        protected List<String> load() {
            return getUniqSystemNames();
        }
    });
:
```

and on reset:

```
    if (selectedSystemNames != null) {
        selectedSystemNames.clear();
        if (target != null) {
            target.add(sapSystemNames);
        }
    }
```

but the selection still remains visible.

Answer (score 1):

You should set an empty collection as a model.

Something like: `choice.setModel(new ArrayList<MyType>())`

Comment: I don't want to remove the objects that can be selected, I want to reset the selected items, i.e. the highlighting

Comment: Check the API. The is a Model for the selected items and another Model for the available items.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I can't seem to find it. I can pass 2 models in the constructor. Which one would it be?

Comment: See https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/792a0a4138aad61dfe63c8bace96648878767003/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/ListMultipleChoice.java#L127. The first model is for the selection. The second is for all available options.

Comment: Thanks again, Martin, it still doesn't work, see my code snippets in my op. Any idea what I'm missing?